# ffmpeg streaming incompatible with output codec id and incorect codec parameters

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

Trying to stream with ffmpeg to a local rtmp server. My comand is like this

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://127.0.0.1:8902 -c copy -f flv "rtmp://192.168.0.101/live/livestream live=1"
```

but it gives me some errors

> [flv @ 00000000003ac0c0] Tag [3][0][0][0]/0x00000003 incompatible with output codec id '86016' ([0][0][0][0])

and

> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invali
>   d data found when processing input

Am i missing a codec?

ffmpeg build: ffmpeg-20140214 x64 windows

Comment: It just says that your codec is incompatible with the FLV container. What are the source audio and video codecs? Can you try another container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FLV/RTMP only supports a handful of codecs.
If your source does not support these formats, you must transcode.

Video:

- H.263
- Screen video
- On2 VP6
- AVC (H.264)

Audio:

- PCM
- ADPCM
- MP3
- Nellymoser
- G.711
- AAC
- Speex

Comment: Yes transcode was the solution the solution looks like this ffmpeg -re -i "http://127.0.0.1:8902" -vcodec libx264 -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -r 25 -s 720x420 -vb 660k -f flv "rtmp://192.168.0.101/live/livestream"